# Cannot Get Get-MgSite to return CreatedBy or CreatedByUser

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-sites

I'm using the Microsoft Graph PowerShell SDK to try and get some data from SharePoint sites using the `Get-MgSite` command. I'm running this command specifically

```
$site = Get-MgSite -SiteId <siteId> -Property Id,DisplayName,Name,WebUrl,CreatedDateTime,CreatedBy,CreatedByUser
```

I also tried this command

```
$site = Get-MgSite -SiteId <siteId> -Property Id,DisplayName,Name,WebUrl,CreatedDateTime,CreatedBy -ExpandProperty CreatedByUser
```

The `$site` variable contains all the requested items from the `Property` parameter except for the `CreatedBy` and `CreatedByUser`. I see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) that the `CreatedBy` and `CreatedByUser` on the `site` resource are actually inherited from the `baseItem` type.

Is it possible to get the `CreatedBy` or `CreatedByUser` properties through the `Get-MgSite` command or is this data not returned through that endpoint?

I know it's not the same thing, but the SharePoint Admin Center does show a value for Created by when you view site properties

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0) , there is no Createdby.CreatedByUser property avaialable ,you can check "createdDateTime" property which is inherited from baseItem , please see the list of property available - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: I never looked too closely at the site JSON representation. I can see now that it doesn't inherit every item from the baseItem resource. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

`createdByUser` is a [relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/baseitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#relationships) defined for `baseItem`, so you need to use expand.

```
Get-MgSite -SiteId $siteId -Property "id,displayName,name,webUrl,createdDateTime,createdBy" -ExpandProperty "createdByUser"
```

But the response from `GET /v1.0/sites/{site-id}` endpoint is quite unexpected

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{site-id}
```

returns properties: `createdDateTime,description,id,lastModifiedDateTime,name, webUrl,displayName,root,siteCollection`.

According to the documentation `createdBy,lastModifiedBy,lastModifiedDateTime` defined on [baseItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/baseitem?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) are missing in the response.

```
GET /v1.0/sites/{site-id}?$select=id,displayName,name,webUrl,createdDateTime,createdBy&$expand=createdByUser
```

returns only `createdDateTime,name,webUrl,displayName`.

`id,createdBy,createdByUser` are missing.

It seems to me that there is a bug on the server side.